# Background color in Inputs HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to change background color only in Inputs: Input1,

Inputs2 doesn't have to change color

But now they all change color

```css
input[type="time"],
area {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

```html
<input type="time" name="x1 //(comment) Input1" />
<input type="time" name="x2 //(comment) Input1" />
<input type="time" name="x3 //(comment) Input2" />
<input type="time" name="x4 //(comment) Input2" />
```

page

> Input1 Input2

> Input1 Input2

How I can do this?
how should I write so that only the chosen ones change color?

Comment: I believe you want to change the background colour of all textboxes where `type=time`. If so, it is working as expected, do you have a demo/jsfiddle showing that it is not working?

Comment: I want to change only Inputs1, not Input2

Comment: input[name= "x1"], input[name= "x2"]{
  background: red;
}

Comment: Please check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59564734/1955268) below. You can do that by applying the `class` to element

Answer (score 2):

You can use `input[name$="Input1"]` selector to set a background color on all elements that have a class attribute value that ends with **Input1**.

```css
input[name$="Input1"] {
  background-color : #d1d1d1; 
}
```

```html
<input type="time" name="x1 //(comment) Input1"/> 
<input type="time" name="x2 //(comment) Input1"/> 
<input type="time" name="x3 //(comment) Input2"/> 
<input type="time" name="x4 //(comment) Input2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by applying `class` to your inputs and change the colour of only those inputs where class is applied.

```css
.changeColor, area {
  background-color : #d1d1d1; 
}
```

```html
<input type="time" class="changeColor" name="x1 //(comment) Input1"/> 
<input type="time" class="changeColor" name="x2 //(comment) Input1"/> 
<input type="time" name="x3 //(comment) Input2"/> 
<input type="time" name="x4 //(comment) Input2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use attribute selector and nth-child, or just *= to detect attributes which contain a certain string.

```
// the attribute contains 'time' and is first child
input[type="time"]:nth-child(1){
  background-color : #d1d1d1; 
}
// the 'attribute contains x1 etc....'
input[name*="x1"]{
  background-color : #d1d1d1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the identifier `name` to specify which inputs to apply the style to if you don't want to give Input1 its own class. In this case we check for `name` ending in `Input1`.

```css
input[name$="Input1"], area {
  background-color : #d1d1d1; 
 }
```

```html
<input type="time" name="x1 Input1"> 
<input type="time" name="x2 Input1"> 
<input type="time" name="x3 Input2"> 
<input type="time" name="x4 Input2">
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="time" name="x1"/> 
<input type="time" name="x2"/> 
<input type="time" name="x3"/> 
<input type="time" name="x4"/>
```

CSS

```
input[name="x1"], 
input[name="x2"] {
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

Your HTML is invalid, it cannot contain comments like that, it will break your validity.

Answer (score 0):

You should give inputs 1 and 2 a specific class :)

```
.grayButton, area {
   background-color: #d1d1d1;
}

<input class="grayButton" type="time" name="x1"/> 
<input class="grayButton" type="time" name="x2"/> 
<input type="time" name="x3"/> 
<input type="time" name="x4"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to identify each one using its name then and set the desired background color...

```
<input type="time" name="x1"/> 
 <input type="time" name="x2"/> 
 <input type="time" name="x3"/> 
 <input type="time" name="x4"/>
```

and your css

```
input[name="x1"] {
background-color : #d1d1d1; 
}

input[name="x2"] {
background-color : lightcoral; 
}

input[name="x3"] {
background-color : lightblue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to help yourself is to create a css class and apply it to your selection.

But if you want to do it as clean as possible you have these ways :

CSS

```css
input[type='time']:nth-child(1), 
input[type='time']:nth-child(2){
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

But you have to be sure that the order will never change

OR this way :

CSS

```css
input[name="x1"], 
input[name="x2"] {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`input[type="time"]` will target all 4 elements, to target selectively, use `name` attribute, e.g. `input[name="x2"]` will only target element with name `x2`

```css
input[type="time"], area {

  background-color : #d1d1d1; 

 }
 
 input[name="x2"], area {

  background-color : red; 

 }
```

```html
<input type="time" name="x1"/> 
 <input type="time" name="x2"/> 
 <input type="time" name="x3"/> 
 <input type="time" name="x4"/>
```

Comment: and how should I write so that only the chosen ones change color?

Comment: @michael1834 you can target the selected elements by name.